# Same repeated class style?

Tags: css

When developing, I normally use a tool set. At the moment it looks something like this:

```
MT10 {margin-top:10px;}
MT20 {margin-top:20px;}
MT30 {margin-top:30px;}
MT40 {margin-top:40px;}

PADB10 {padding-bot:10px;}
PADB20 {padding-bot:20px;}
PADB30 {padding-bot:30px;}
PADB40 {padding-bot:40px;}
```

Is it possible to have one class that can detected any number I put after MT or PADB? I'd imagine a generic class that I can add a number to that would effect the styling. Is this possible?

Comment: Not with pure CSS, no.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a step short of akin to just using inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with pure CSS, but if you really want to make dynamic CSS you could make a PHP file that returns CSS-file headers and contents and include it like a normal external stylesheet. I would go for the PHP option if there are a lot of dynamic factors related to database contents or other server-sided data.

**Example** (not tested)

```
header("Content-type: text/css");

$prefixes = array('MT' => 'margin-top', 'PADB' => 'padding-bot');
foreach ($prefixes as $prefix_key => $prefix_value) {
    for ($i = 10; $i <= 40; $i += 10) {
        echo $prefix_key.$i.' {'.$prefix_value.':'.$i.'px;}'."\n";
    }
}
```

You could also use a CSS Framework, like SASS (http://sass-lang.com/) or LessCSS (http://lesscss.org/) if it's not content-related and you want to use a CSS framework.

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS, this is not possible.

However, if you use something like [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature), it can be achieved.

eg:

```
.margin-top(@margin) {
  margin-top: @margin;
}
```

Then, give each a class of:

```
.margin-top(10px);
.margin-top:(20px);
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Can be done Using Simple Jquery-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function myfunction() { //on document ready
        $("[class^='MT']").each(function (index) {  //select each element which starts with MT.
            var cls = $(this).attr('class');  //get the class of it
            cls = parseInt(cls.substring(2)); // select the substring that has number, here its 2, as the number starts after MT.
            $(this).css("margin-top", cls + "px"); //assign margin-top property to that element
        });

        $("[class^='PADB']").each(function (index) { //select each element which starts with PADB.
            var cls = $(this).attr('class');
            cls = parseInt(cls.substring(4)); // here its four as the number that needs to be selected is after PADB.
            $(this).css("padding-bottom", cls + "px"); // assign padding-bottom property to this element.
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here u can c the [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gurunave/m6Kjs/2/)